# How to check the value of a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, typeinfo

I want to use the alias based on the value in template parameter. Something like this:

```
If W > 32:
template<size_t W>
using int_t = My_Int<W, int64_t>;

Else:
template<size_t W>
using int_t = My_Int<W, int32_t>;
```

I also tried std::conditional, but didn't find a good way to do it..
How should I do that? Thanks!

Comment: You should post what you tried and explain why it was 'not good'. Otherwise this just looks like a request for documentation/tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Using `std::conditional` you would have

```
template<size_t W>
using int_t = std::conditional_t<(W > 32), My_Int<W, int64_t>, My_Int<W, int32_t>>;
```

where `My_Int<W, int64_t>` is used when `W > 32` is true and `My_Int<W, int32_t>` is used when it is false.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) for it, e.g.

```
template<size_t W>
using int_t = typename std::conditional<(W > 32), My_Int<W, int64_t>, My_Int<W, int32_t>>::type;
```

Or since C++14:

```
template<size_t W>
using int_t = std::conditional_t<(W > 32), My_Int<W, int64_t>, My_Int<W, int32_t>>;
```

Note that you need to add parentheses for the condition `W > 32`; otherwise `W` will be considered as the only template argument, which won't work because `std::conditional` expects three ones.

Answer (score 2):

A little-less type-writing version of `std::conditional_t` solutions

```
template <std::size_t W>
using int_t = My_Int<W, std::conditional_t<(W > 32), int64_t, int32_t>>;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template<size_t W>
using int_t = std::conditional_t<(W > 32), My_Int<W, int64_t>, My_Int<W, int32_t>>;
```

will work on C++14.

Comment: Why was this worth posting when 2 answers already said the same thing verbatim 10 minutes earlier?